# Solving Differential Equation about rate of infected computers

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, differential

I am having some trouble solving this differential equation for the rate of infected computers in a botnet at time t

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x }{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{1}{c\nu (1-x) + \beta x(1-x) - \gamma x}$$

with $$x(0) = 1$$ i.e at time 0, there is one computer in the botnet.

I am trying to get this in terms of x(t) but the algebra is becoming quite complex for me, can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: Solving $\frac{dt}{dx}=c\nu (1-x) + \beta x(1-x) - \gamma x$ first could be an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, use variable separable method as follows $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{c\nu(1-x)+\beta x(1-x)-\gamma x}$$
$$(c\nu(1-x)+\beta x(1-x)-\gamma x)\ dx=dt$$
$$c\nu\int \ dx+(\beta-c\nu-\gamma)\int x\ dx-\beta\int x^2\ dx=\int \ dt$$
$$c\nu x+(\beta-c\nu-\gamma)\frac{x^2}{2}-\beta\frac{x^3}{3}=t+C$$
now, setting $x=1$ at $t=0$, we get $$c\nu \cdot 1+(\beta-c\nu-\gamma)\frac{1^2}{2}-\beta\frac{1^3}{3}=0+C\implies C=c\nu+(\beta-c\nu-\gamma)\frac{1}{2}-\beta\frac{1}{3}$$
I hope you can take it from here

Comment: Thank you, I shall attempt to rearrange this in terms of x(t) equals something. I shall respond again if I get stuck